# Docker node.js won't create image

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

my image:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:17.5

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install -g npm@8.5.1
RUN npm ci

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

my error:

```
[+] Building 71.9s (10/11)                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 372B                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:17.5                                                                                                                                                                       0.7s
 => [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/node:17.5@sha256:a0590a265b222387d756ba357c4a9875778f1a7638ac011f3fb4942d3b7ae5c0                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.2s
 => => transferring context: 3.06MB                                                                                                                                                                                                1.1s
 => CACHED [2/7] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [3/7] COPY package.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [4/7] COPY package-lock.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [5/7] RUN npm install -g npm@8.5.1                                                                                                                                                                                             9.2s
 => ERROR [6/7] RUN npm ci                                                                                                                                                                                                        60.8s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 > [6/7] RUN npm ci:                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#10 11.25 npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.                                                                                                                                  
#10 11.80 npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated                                                                                                                             
#10 11.94 npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated                                                                                                                     
#10 15.43 npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142                                                                                                           
#10 24.18 npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
#10 39.71 npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
#10 60.62 npm ERR! code 1
#10 60.62 npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/node-sass
#10 60.62 npm ERR! command failed
#10 60.62 npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
#10 60.62 npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.5.0 | linux | arm64
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executable path is "/usr/bin/python3"
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - executing "/usr/bin/python3" to get version
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb find Python - version is "3.9.2"
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.2 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 17.5.0
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '17.5.0' ]
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "17.5.0"
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 17.5.0
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 17.5.0
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /root/.cache/node-gyp/17.5.0
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb created nodedir /root/.cache
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.5.0/node-v17.5.0-headers.tar.gz
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb command remove [ '17.5.0' ]
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb remove using node-gyp dir: /root/.cache/node-gyp
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb remove removing target version: 17.5.0
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp verb remove removing development files for version: 17.5.0
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.5.0/node-v17.5.0-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:110:14)
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:28)
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:538:35)
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.76-linuxkit
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/node-sass
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.5.0
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
#10 60.63 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
#10 60.63 npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
#10 60.63 
#10 60.64 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#10 60.64 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-21T14_36_45_600Z-debug-0.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm ci]: exit code: 1
```

Comment: Did you consider making it _not_ `--silent`, to see if there's more information? Also note in this kind of context [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci) is probably the option to go for.

Comment: can you downgrade node version and see whether it works

Comment: @Shiju i downgraded to `13.12.0-alpine` but same error

Answer (score 0):

I see the following line in docker file is throwing error.

```
# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

Can you replace it as a

```
# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH="/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

and try

refer link : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement

Comment: any changes and same error.